# How can I set only one field on a Child Form in Symfony to be required?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony6

My parent form type is using a child form type.

I want to make one field on the child form type required, and the rest of the fields optional.

In a perfect world, the code below would work and just the `boo` field from the child form would be required when the form is rendered. It does not work however, and all of the fields in the child class will be optional.

```php
    // Parent form
    
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('foo')
            ->add('bar', ChildFormType::class, [
                'inherit_data' => true
            ])
        ;
    }
```

```php
    // Child form

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('baz')
            ->add('boo', null, ['required' => true])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'required' => false,
        ]);
    }
```

I can actually fix this and get the result I want by adjusting the child type, first by removing the `configureOptions()` method and then manually setting all the form fields I want to be be optional as `required => false`:

```php
    // Edited child form

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('baz', null, ['required' => false])
            ->add('boo')
        ;
    }
```

In this minimal example this is fine, however when there are many form fields in the child type I have to add `['required' => false]` to every single one of them and it feels like I'm missing a simpler way of doing things.

The fact that I get the result I want one way round but not the other is a bit confusing to me also (setting all but one field to `required => false` rather than setting one field to `required => true`).

Is there some option I can set in the parent form type to respect the options I set in the child type, or just some way of achieving what I want without a load of ugly duplication? I'm struggling to find an answer in the docs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

setting the default option to `false` and then adding the `required` option to `true` to a field should work fine.

```php
class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('requiredField', TextType::class, [
                'required' => true
            ])
            ->add('optionalField1', TextType::class)
            ->add('optionalField2', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'required' => false,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work in the example I have described. I would have expected it to and it was the first thing I tried, but what led to me posting on SO is the fact that it didn't.